# Using java-ews-api and office 2013 - The Autodiscover service couldn't be located

Tags: ewsjavaapi

I am trying to connect with this code and others similar that I have taken from the getting started guide and no matter what I do I keep getting the error:

> The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.

I cannot seem to find or resolve this.

```
import java.net.URI;

import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeVersion;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Folder;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WellKnownFolderName;

public class Main {

    public static class RedirectionUrlCallback implements IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl {
        public boolean autodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback(String redirectionUrl) {
          return redirectionUrl.toLowerCase().startsWith("https://");
        }
    }

    public static ExchangeService connectViaExchangeAutodiscover(String email, String password) {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        try {

            service.setCredentials(new WebCredentials(email, password));
            service.autodiscoverUrl(email, new RedirectionUrlCallback());
            service.setTraceEnabled(true);
            Folder inbox = Folder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
            System.out.println("messages: " + inbox.getTotalCount());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return service;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
          System.out.println("Hello World");
          ExchangeService service = connectViaExchangeAutodiscover("user@domain.com", "xxxxxx");

      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

This is a trace report if someone can help me troubleshoot it.

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
Determining which endpoints are enabled for host wont let me post the link

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
No Autodiscover endpoints are available for host wont let me post the link

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
Determining which endpoints are enabled for host wont let me post the link

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
No Autodiscover endpoints are available for host wont let me post the link

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
Trying to get Autodiscover redirection URL from wont let me post the link.

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
No Autodiscover redirection URL was returned.

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
Trying to get Autodiscover host from DNS SRV record for xxxxx.com.

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
DnsQuery returned error error 'null' error code 0x{1:X8}.

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
No appropriate SRV record was found.

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
No matching Autodiscover DNS SRV records were found.

Type:AutodiscoverResponse Message:
Autodiscover service call failed with error 'The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.'. Will try legacy service

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
Trying to call Autodiscover for xxxxxx@xxxxx.com on wont let me post the link.

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
null failed: wont let me post the link (wont let me post the link : Connection error )

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
Trying to call Autodiscover for xxxxxx@xxxxx.com on wont let me post the link.

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
null failed: wont let me post the link (wont let me post the link : Connection error )

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
Trying to get Autodiscover redirection URL from wont let me post the link.

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
No Autodiscover redirection URL was returned.

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
Trying to get Autodiscover host from DNS SRV record for xxxxx.com.

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
DnsQuery returned error error 'null' error code 0x{1:X8}.

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
No appropriate SRV record was found.

Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
No matching Autodiscover DNS SRV records were found.

Comment: have you tried using the https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/ to try using the service? Maybe this can help to verify its an API or connectivity/configuration problem.

Comment: They are quite strict at work about installing software so I probably would not be able to do it.

Comment: I should also note that I have tried the manual option as well and this has not worked for me ( again, I followed the guidelines provided by the getting started guide).

Comment: from the log I would say you are missing the appropriate DNS records. Sorry but you need to verify if autodiscover works for you at all (ewseditor will do the trick) or if its a general config problem.

Comment: Okay I will try and get them to let me download it and I will definitely post a solution to this once I figure this out.  Thank you.

Comment: For anyone following, turns out this was an issue with my dependencies.  I did not have my gradle integration set up properly:   dependencies {
    compile 'com.microsoft.ews-java-api:ews-java-api:2.0'
}

Comment: @paul how dependency can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Order to follow to avoid such errors:

1. Set Credentials
2. Set impersonationId
3. Set autoDiscovery
4. Set anchorMailbox